# My cygwin gcc report conflicting types error when building dynamic link library using JNI

Tags: java-native-interface, cross-compiling, dynamic-library, datalog, cygwin-64

I was using cygwin gcc (7.4.0-x64) on windows to build dynamic link library for java.

Here reports the error:
H:\ddlog/java/ddlogapi.c:1057:28: error: conflicting types for 'Java_ddlogapi_DDlogAPI_ddlog_1is_1int'
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_ddlogapi_DDlogAPI_ddlog_1is_1int(
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from H:\ddlog/java/ddlogapi.c:12:0:
H:\ddlog/java/ddlogapi_DDlogAPI.h:423:28: note: previous declaration of 'Java_ddlogapi_DDlogAPI_ddlog_1is_1int' was here
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_ddlogapi_DDlogAPI_ddlog_1is_1int

It seems to me that there is no difference between these two return types, why this error happen anyway?
Can anyone help me figure this out and how to solve this problem?

I have successfully built java library in linux using cc command, which is gcc (7.5.0-x64), so I pretty sure there is no problem in the above .c and .h files, could it be the platform-specific difference that invoke this error?

Comment: Edit your question with the full signature of your function in both header and C file. Perhaps the problem is in the arguments instead.

Comment: Voting to close as "needs more debugging information".

Comment: @Botje Thanks for your insights, It is indeed the inconsistent arguments that makes this problem. However, even if I correct the arguments, the compilation still fails. I am trying to do the cross-compile in linux to build the .dll for windows, anyway thx for your advice.

Comment: Compilation still fails how?

Comment: It turns out that I should use the Mingw64 instead of Cygwin64 gcc, I don't know why but the problem is solved, thank you for asking.